# xsl text and normal string

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

What is the differnce between

```
    <xsl:param name="abc">123</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="def"><xsl:text>123</xsl:text></xsl:param>
```

They both work same but is there some difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

<xsl:text> will allow you to manipulate the text (escape as well as white space):

> `<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes|no">`

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256107(v=vs.110).aspx:

> In a style sheet, text can be generated to the literal result tree
>   with or without <xsl:text>. However, with this element you can exert
>   some control over the white space created by the style sheet. For
>   example, to make your style sheet more readable, you might want to
>   write one element per line in a template, and indent some lines. Doing
>   so introduces white space as part of the template rule. This might or
>   might not be a desired effect of the transformation. Sometimes you
>   might want to introduce a white space character to separate two data
>   values. You can use an <xsl:text> element to accomplish this. White
>   space enclosed within <xsl:text> is output to the result tree.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for using `<xsl:text>` is that whitespace arount text XSLT stylesheets is normally discarded/stripped (http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#strip). Text enclosed in `<xsl:text>` is the exception to that rule. So if you want to explicitly output spaces, tabs, or newlines you may need to use `<xsl:text>`

`<xsl:text>` also allows case-by-case control over the output escaping mode. That's less frequently used; disabling output escaping is usually the wrong solution unless you're generating non-XML/non-HTML output.

[Apologies for the confusion, now corrected above. I just noticed that I had indeed been looking at a Working Draft of XSLT 1.0, not the final RECcomendation. Mea culpa, mea culpa, mea maxima culpa.]

Comment: "as of XSLT 2.0, <xsl:text> also allows case-by-case control over the output escaping mode. (In XSLT 1.0 that can only be set on a global level, via the attribute on <xsl:output>.)" I don't think that is correct.

Comment: Rechecked the 1.0 Recommendation one more time, and I don't see it. Feel free to point out where I missed it.

Comment: I think you meant to write "control over *white space stripping*", not *output escaping*? That would also be more in context with your first paragraph, now that I read it again.

Comment: Well, the thing is that in **XSLT 1.0**, `disable-output-escaping` is an allowed attribute of the `<xsl:text>` and the `<xsl:value-of>` elements. It is **not** an allowed attribute of the `<xsl:output>` element.